# Android - Clearing backstack with an Intent NOT called from an Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, android-activity, back-stack

I'm trying to implement a small slideshow similar to those used by many apps as an intro, such as Google Docs.

I separated the adapter from the activity as to keep everything tidy:

```
public class IntroActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private int[] mResources = {
            R.drawable.slide1,
            R.drawable.slide2,
            R.drawable.slide3,
            R.drawable.slide4
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_intro);

        CustomPagerAdapter customPagerAdapter = new CustomPagerAdapter(this, mResources);

        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(customPagerAdapter);
    }

}
```

And the following code in my `CustomPagerAdapter` handles the click event of a button on the last slide which opens the `MainActivity` through an intent. Pretty standard stuff:

```
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

        if (position == (mResources.length - 1)) {
            System.out.println("POSITION " + position);

            View itemView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.pager_last_item, container, false);

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.lastImageView);
            imageView.setImageResource(mResources[position]);

            Button btn = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_open_main_activity);
            btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MainActivity.class);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                    //TODO destroy IntroActivity.java
                }
            });

            container.addView(itemView);

            return itemView;
          }
         (...) //if not the last slide...

   }
```

But it doesn't seem to work, even with those Intent flags. I have no way to access the `finish()` method from the `IntroActivity`. 
The app runs fine, but when I press the back button in the `MainActivity`, it brings me back to the last slide. 
Is there a way to fix it?

EDIT - This is how I'm creating the PagerAdapter. I'm just passing the context and the resource array from IntroActivity:

```
public class CustomPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
    private int[] mResources;

    public CustomPagerAdapter(Context context, int[] mResources) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.mResources = mResources;
    }
```

Comment: As a little addendum, can someone clarify if passing Activity references to normal classes is good practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `android:noHistory="true"` attribute in IntroActivity   declaration in manifest.

refer [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#AndroidManifestActivity_noHistory)

Or you can pass activity reference to the fragment or the adapter claa via a constructor and call activity.finish()

something like `new Adapter(mActivity)` and call `mActivity.finish()`

Comment: I'm a bit dubious about that solution... They said I should avoid it in case I implement Login via facebook for example. Which I eventually will, since this is just a spike for a project

Comment: So in IntroActivity I should do something like CustomPagerAdapter customPagerAdapter = new CustomPagerAdapter(/*reference here*/ ,this, mResources);?

I'm still pretty new to Android. I understand that passing 'this' refers to the context, and it's not a direct reference to the Activity

Comment: Well, eventually I did exactly what you proposed, and it has worked. Thank you :)